# I am facing issue with Azure Virtual Machine while hosting my website through IIS Manager

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure-virtual-machine, azure-webapps

I am using Azure Virtual Server for hosting website through IIS Manager. But I am getting attached error every week and I have to restart the website from IIS Manager to work again.

Thanks in advance for your response!!!

I tried many fixes like keep services running but I am not to find exact solution on the problem.

[Screenshot for Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRI37.png)

Comment: That error just says there was an issue launching your ASP.NET Core app. You need to check the Event Viewer and get the error message that shows up when this happens. That will tell you what the actual problem is, then you can begin addressing that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the hostingModel attribute value is OutOfProcess or InProcess, try changing it to OutOfProcess, and then restart the project.

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Comment: Just changing the hosting model without a clear reason to isn't a good idea, nor is failing to disclose the implications of doing this. The question isn't yet clear on what the underlying problem actually is, so you should wait until the issue becomes clear before leaving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mason pointed out, HTTP error 500.30 indicates that the ASP.NET Core app failed to start. This error can occur due to various reasons such as missing dependencies, incorrect configuration, or runtime issues.

I understand you have tried multiple things to keep the services running and your website works fine for 1 week. You need to fetch more details into the error and isolate the issue, here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

Just to confirm, does this website work fine as expected locally? Hosting a website no an Azure VM, you would typically do the same thing, as you would on- prem.

1. Check the application logs: You can check the application logs to see if there are any errors or exceptions that can help you identify the issue. You can find the logs in the Event Viewer under the "Windows Logs" section.
2. Check the event logs on the virtual machine to see if there are any error messages that can help identify the issue.
3. Ensure that all required dependencies for your app are installed on the VM.
4. Also, run the performance diagnostics tool on your Azure VM to isolate VM specific issues, which is surfacing to website hosted on it.
   This tool helps you troubleshoot performance issues that can affect a VM. For a quick check on known issues and best practices, and complex problems that involve slow VM performance or high usage of CPU, disk space, or memory.

Checkout these docs for more info:

[Azure VM performance-diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/performance-diagnostics)

[Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service and IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for your response.

 This time we have collected below logs.

Level Source Event ID Task Category
Error MSSQLSERVER 14151 Server
Error IIS AspNetCore Module V2 1007 None
Error IIS AspNetCore Module V2 1018 None